# Unusual break in data output

Tags: php, css, formatting

I have been trying to determine what the source of my formatting issue in my php code. The mysql result should show the top 10 rows and I am formatting as such. There is a LIMIT of 10, but for some reason between the 9th and 10th row there is a break in the data.

I'be been racking my brains trying to figure out what is happening. I've attached an image demonstrating the break.[image: Gap]

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'someuser', 'somepassword',    
'somedatabase');

// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());

}

// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

// SELECT sql query
$sql = "SELECT c.*, s.species AS species1, b.breed AS breed1, m.modality 
AS modality1, a.area AS area1, cl.clinician AS clin FROM tbl_cases c

LEFT JOIN tbl_species s
ON c.species = s.speciesID

LEFT JOIN tbl_breed b
ON c.breed = b.breedID

LEFT JOIN tbl_modality m
ON c.modality = m.modalityID

LEFT JOIN tbl_area a
ON c.area = a.areaID

LEFT JOIN tbl_clinician cl
ON c.clinician = cl.clinicianID

ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10"; 

// perform the query and store the result
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// if the $result contains at least one row
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row from $result

echo '<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 
5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-
break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-
weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-
width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
</style>
    <table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 
1190px">
    <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 30px">  
    <col style="width: 125px">
    <col style="width: 100px">
    <col style="width: 250px">
    <col style="width: 80px">
    <col style="width: 200px">
    <col style="width: 50px">
    <col style="width: 180px">
    <col style="width: 175px">
    </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e">ID</th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><div align="left">Date:</div></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><div align="left">Case No.:</div></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><div align="left">Patient:</div></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><div align="left">Species:</div></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><div align="left">Breed:</div></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><div align="left">Mod:</div></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><div align="left">Area:</div></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><div align="left">Clinician:</div></th>
  </tr>
</table>';
$c = false;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())   

{ 
echo '<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 
5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-
break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-
weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-
width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;} 
</style>
<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 1190px">
    <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 30px">  
    <col style="width: 125px">
    <col style="width: 100px">
    <col style="width: 250px">
    <col style="width: 80px">
    <col style="width: 200px">
    <col style="width: 50px">
    <col style="width: 180px">
    <col style="width: 175px">
    </colgroup>';

  if($row['modality']=='1') // Modality = CT
     echo '<tr bgcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['caseID'].'</div></th>
        <th><div align="left">'.date('d-M-Y',    
strtotime($row['date'])).'</div></th>
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['patientID'].'</div></th>
        <th><div     
align="left">'.$row['lastname'].',&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row['firstname'].'</div>    
</th>
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['species1'].'</div></th>
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['breed1'].'</div></th>
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['modality1'].'</div></th>
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['area1'].'</div></th>
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['clin'].'</div></th>
        </tr>';

 else if($row['modality']=='2')// Modality = MRI
     echo '<tr bgcolor="#ECF6CE">
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['caseID'].'</div></th>
        <th><div align="left">'.date('d-M-Y', 
strtotime($row['date'])).'</div></th>
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['patientID'].'</div></th>
        <th><div 
align="left">'.$row['lastname'].',&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row['firstname'].'</div>   
</th>
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['species1'].'</div></th>
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['breed1'].'</div></th>
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['modality1'].'</div></th>
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['area1'].'</div></th>
        <th><div align="left">'.$row['clin'].'</div></th>
        </tr>
    </table>';
  }
}
else {
  echo 'No cases.';
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: put `<style></style>` outside the loop, and why even you repeating the same `<style></style>`?

Comment: also you have `<table>` starting right after `loop` but `</table>` is in the 2nd else condition, you have many problems in table layout.

Comment: It looks like you are creating a new table for each row result. I would have expected you to open and close the table tags outside of your while loop and just add rows to the table within. Also, you close the table if the modality is 2 but not if it is 1. that is probably what is causing your current issues - but you should refactor anyway.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I am learning, that's why there are a lot of problems. I'm trying to learn things on my own and sometimes it's all so new and strange. Additionally, learning on your own and going from mysql to mysqli has not been very pretty either. I've found the error. I've moved the </table> out of the loop and now it's fine. Regarding the repeating style, I'm not sure why. That's how the example that I went with had it.

Comment: @DaniëlCronk I don't know the example part but for `<style>` inside loop, I can give you an example, as you have limit of  `10` rows so the `<style>` inside loop is repeating 10 times and imagine if you lift the limit or increase the limit to fetch 100 rows or 500 rows so the `<style>` inside loop will be repeating 100 or 500 times respectively so put it outside the loop or even good if you remove the `<style>` which is inside the loop because you already have the same `<style>` after `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {`